# global variable vs getter functions vs function variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, global-variables

I have a scenario that can be implemented in multiple ways. I need suggestion which is more optimized / python way of implementing and why ?

lets consider nested function calls as
funca1 -> funca2 -> funca3 ->funca4
funcb1 -> funcb2 -> funcb3 ->funcb4

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    funca1()
    funcb1()
```

and varx variable is only used / or needed by funca4 and funcb3.
then we have below options

1. create varx as global variable and use it funca4 and funcb3 with out passing through all the functions
2. pass the varx variable across all the functions even through its used only in two functions
3. create another functions get_varx() function and only use this inside funca4, funcb4.

This can also be achieved by creating class and assigning varx as property . But current design of the project doesn't allow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a demo code with the scenarios you gave, and timed the execution time using the `time` module and obtained the following results:

Fastest Execution Rankings:

1. Creating another function to get the value.
2. Creating `varx` as a global variable.
3. Passing the `varx` variable accross all the functions.

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-code-in-python). I used `perf_counter()` method to obtain the results.

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-code-in-python). I used `perf_counter()` method to obtain the results.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization is relative.

You can optimize by:-

1. your code to have less lines/characters
2. you want minimum memory consumption
3. you want minimum time required.

Minimum time would be another function method

Minimum memory and minimum lines would be global variable.

Passing a variable through all is just unnecessary and duplicates the variables in each local scope consuming alot of memory hence this should be avoided.